# dpkg error processing packages, cannot complete install desktop/GUI from terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, vnc

I've rented a VPS with ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have googled my way to tutorials and basic terminal knowledge. I want to set up a ubunutu desktop so I can also navigate using TightVNC. This whole process unfortunately gets stuck at some error codes. I've searched this and many other sites but I can't find a solution to my specific situation. However I have learned that `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` is a generic error code as well as `dpkg: error processing package "x" (--configure)`.

From what I can figure out from the code my install is not completed because 12 packages are unconfigured:

```
 bluez
 bluez-alsa:amd64
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 gnome-shell
 gdm
 gnome-user-share
 ubuntu-desktop
 unity-control-center-signon
 webaccounts-extension-common
 xul-ext-webaccounts
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to fix this since I'm a complete beginner. Bellow I will past some more error code example so you guys can better help me out. I've tried to learn/find as much info as I could on my own but I'm really stuck and hope that this community can help me.

```
root@h2511510:~#
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [J/n] J
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-alsa:amd64:
 bluez-alsa:amd64 depends on bluez; however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez-alsa:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 4.36); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

  # ETC ETC ETC, same logs for all 12 processes #
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 bluez-alsa:amd64
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 gnome-shell
 gdm
 gnome-user-share
 ubuntu-desktop
 unity-control-center-signon
 webaccounts-extension-common
 xul-ext-webaccounts
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@h2511510:~#
```

Comment: I found this topic http://askubuntu.com/questions/151510/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency-problems

And used `apt-get remove #followed by the above mentioned 12 packages#` and the `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Trying to install only bluez gnome-bluetooth gnome-shell gdm and gnome-user-share are left. However when I `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` all the original 12 errors are back.

Comment: also tried suggestions from this topic but the same errors keep persisting, I'm getting really curious about what's going on here...http://askubuntu.com/questions/103834/how-do-i-force-configuration-of-partially-installed-packages

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get --purge remove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Worked for me in the end, hopefully someone can use this for future reference!

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a: Unknown option: a

Answer (score 8):

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/the-package-causing-error
```

If you have an error like following

> dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-web-config (--remove):
>        subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
>       Errors were encountered while processing:
>        some-package // this would be different for you
>       E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

and none of user489207's instruction worked for you, then try

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/some-package*
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing the same problem. Instead of using dpkg I used *gdebi*.

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

sudo gdebi dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb
```