# How to fix these broken package dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Disclaimer: I already asked this question on another [SE site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254757/how-to-reinstall-qgis-from-scratch-on-ubuntu/254768), because I initially thought this is an issue caused by a specific GIS software. The more I looked into it, I realised that it's `dpkg` that's causing the problems, so here goes:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 (kernel 4.10.0-33-generic)

I wanted to upgrade the package `qgis`, but received an error message:

> /usr/bin/qgis.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libqgis_core.so.2.14.17: undefined symbol: OGR_F_SetFieldNull

I tried reinstalling the whole thing with

```
sudo apt purge qgis* python-qgis* --auto-remove
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

However, these are the error messages I end up with:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-provider-grass:
 qgis-provider-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-provider-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis-provider-grass (= 2.14.17+dfsg-1~xenial3); however:
  Package qgis-provider-grass is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                        dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-provider-grass
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

By now, I tried fixing `dpkg` like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109703/151340); reinstalling `dpkg` gives me the same error message as above if QGIS is installed. Obviously, there are some leftovers of the old installation that `remove --purge` doesn't get rid of and I'm out of ideas what else to try. Any idea how this can be possible?

Edit: [Here's](https://pastebin.com/0ks5XiGa) the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Can you pastebin the results of `dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: @mac9416: I added it to the question.

Comment: @karpfen try to remove packages ` dpkg` command.

Comment: @Nullpointer I tried that and removed all qgis* packages. After that `dpkg --configure -a` didn't produce any error anymore. Then I installed QGIS again and I'm back to the usual error messages.

Comment: @karpfen have you removed with `dpkg` ?

Comment: Yes, so `sudo dpkg --remove qgis` for example.

Comment: maybe related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina